# <a> and <img> tag not working

Tags: wp-query, html

when I try to show the thumbnail image with a href tag to refer to the post page it only shows the link next to the picture and the image is not clickable.

```
echo "<head>
      <style>
      img {
          margin-left: 25px;
          margin-right: 25px;
          }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>

      <a href=".the_permalink()." blank='_blank'>
      <img src=".the_post_thumbnail('video')." >
      </a>
      </body>";
```

Anybody knows a fix for that?

Comment: Try `target="_blank"` in stead of `blank="_blank"`?

Comment: @cjbj tried it already not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself:

```
echo "<head>
            <style>
        img {
            margin-left: 25px;
            margin-right: 25px;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>


        <a href='".get_the_permalink()."' target='_blank'>";
        the_post_thumbnail('video');
        echo "</a>

        </body>";
```

Answer (score 2):

`the_permalink()` and `the_post_thumbnail()` echo their output. Use the `"get_*` version of those functions, [`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) and [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) when concatenating a string to be output.

Both `the_post_thumbnail()` and `get_the_post_thumbnail()` will echo/return `<img>` tags so don't wrap their output in an `<img>` tag because it's already taken care of by those functions.

The original HTML posted is missing quotes and I'm not sure why you have the `<head>`, `<style>`, and `<body>` tags in there; those tags are not necessary.

This code will output a linked image:

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" target="_blank">' .
     get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'video' ) . '</a>';
?>
```

Comment: example not working for me :/

Comment: It works; I've tested it :D Try editing your original post and add the code for the entire template being used.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' . get_the_permalink() . '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in <path> on line 91

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" blank="_blank">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('video'); ?>
</a>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'd do some more reading up on PHP.

You should use as little PHP as possible. You don't want to be echoing your entire template.

Also, use get_header and get_footer functions. That means you can add your style to your CSS.

The reason it didn't work to begin with is some functions literally echo data. Others just return it to do as you need.

Comment: example not working for me :/